# How to combine elements of three arrays to get the wanted result

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview:

Given three arrays of unequal sizes and a particular number, I have to select one number from each of the three arrays, and, by dividing the numbers from array1 and array2 and multiplying it with division of numbers from array2 and array3, find whether the a particular number can be obtained or not?

```
For example: If I have three arrays: 
Array1: 4
Array2: 3 6
Array3: 2 3 8
```

And I have to find if the number (1/4) can be obtained or not? Yes, it can be since if I select 4 from first array, and 6 from second, and then, 3 from second array and 8 from third array, I can have,

```
(4/6)*(3/8) which makes it as 1/4.
```

How to proceed with this question? I couldn't come up with anything solid for this. Thanks!

Comment: what's the range of all the input?

Comment: One way I thought of was O(n^3) but it will surpass the time constraints since individual values can be upto 10^9.

Comment: @rohansingh, do you have time, space constraints?

Comment: If the arrays are small you can surely just enumerate every possible combination to see if one works (four nested for loops). Any other answer is premature optimization until the array sizes are known.

Comment: @IanMercer This is not what premature optimization means.

Comment: @amit: Your own algorithm, for example attempts to use storage instead of computation without knowing which is preferred. You *prematurely optimized* the answer without knowing the constraints. When allocations are expensive the brute force approach will win.

Comment: @IanMercer: Premature optimization is when you write code that's hard to read, hard to modify, or brittle (only works for the exact kind of input you're currently feeding it).  e.g. hard-coding constants in a language where that's faster than defining named constants.  Choosing good algorithms is a different thing.  A simple brute-force approach is a well-considered choice if you *know* your problem sizes will be small, or can live with the bad performance on the occasional large problem.  Either way, "premature optimization" is more specific than just any choice made without profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Let `M` be your desired number.

You can go through all pairs `(i,j)` from (array2,array3) (there are O(n2*n3) of those), and store the value `array2[i]/array3[j]` in a set.

Then, iterate over all pairs `k,l` in array1, array2 (there are `O(n1*n2)` of those), and check if there is a value in the set `x` such that `array1[k]/array2[l] * x = M`.

This can be done by simply checking if the value `x = M*array2[l] / array1[k]` exists in the table.

Assuming balanced tree implementation for the set, this will take `O(log(n2*n3) * (n1*n2 + n2*n3))` time.

It can be improved a bit for unequal size arrays by choosing to store array that minimizes the summation of products: `x1*x2 + x3*x4` (where x1,x2,x3,x4) are the sizes of arrays, array2 "gets" two variables in this equation), so you can basically have the following "store" combinations:

- array2/array3 (as in the example above)
- array1/array2 (and check for x=M*array3/array2)
- array2/array2 (and check for x=M*array3/array1)
- array1/array3 (and check for x=M*array2/array2)
- array1*array2 (and check for x=M*array3*array2
- 1/(array2*array3) (and check for x=M/(array2*array1)

Comment: I am not sure but can't get why are you storing division pairs from third array? Shouldn't it be the pairs from array2 divided by array3? And you get O(n1*n2 + n2*n3)?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am doing this "trick" to get better complexity (quadric instead of cubic). I am storing all pairs, and checking for pairs. This still guarantees all possibilities are checked, and reduces complexity.

Comment: I mean shouldn't this `array3[i]/array3[j]` be this `array2[i]/array3[j]`?

Comment: n1/n2 * n2/n3 is the same as n1/n3 * n2/n2, so his solution is correct, but it should be array2/array2 (not array3/array3), and array1/array3

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, I confused and thaught array3 appears twice and not array2. thanks for your comment. fixed.\

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate candidates and reduce worst-case time complexity to `O(n2 * n3 + n1 * n2)` by looking at multiples rather than quotients:

First, hash only those multiples, `a2 * a3; a2 ∈ array2, a3 ∈ array3`, evenly divided by the target denominator. In your example, these would be, `{3 * 8 / 4 = 6, 6 * 2 / 4 = 3, 6 * 8 / 4 = 12}`.

Then, look for a multiple, `a1 * a2 / target numerator; a1 ∈ array1, a2 ∈ array2`, in the hash table. In your example, that would be `4 * 3 / 1`.

(Reverse the process for integer targets, first hashing multiples of elements from `array1` and `array2` evenly divided by the target, then match with element multiples from `array2` and `array3`.)

Assuming average complexity for the hash table (`O(n)` construction, `O(1)` lookup), overall worst-case time complexity ought to be `O(n2 * n3 + n1 * n2)`. For large input cardinality, sorted hash table and arrays could allow earlier detection of no solution.